# Collecting int value from the Mono<Entity> object using WebFlux

Tags: java, repository, spring-webflux

What is the correct way for collecting the value from the Mono object?
I have an entity called Student which has both user and student id values.

```
Mono<Student> student = studentRepository.findStudentByUserid(id);
```

and I want to use studentId (`student.getStudentId()`) to save a new value in different table

```
StudentSubject ss;
ss.setStudentId(student.getStudentId());
studentsubjectRepository.save(ss);
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lacks a bit of details, so I'll assume some things from this point.

Let's say your app is using this code:

```
Mono<StudentSubject> studentSubject = studentRepository.findStudentByUserid(id)
    .flatMap(student -> {
        StudentSubject subject = new StudentSubject();
        subject.setStudentId(student.getStudentId());
        return studentsubjectRepository.save(subject);
    });
```

Using the `flatMap` operator allows you to chain calls in reactive fashion.

Several things can happen here:

- there is a student with that id, a subject is created with that information and is returned, as long as something subscribes to this `Mono`. The subscription part usually happens in Spring WebFlux so you just need to return that `Mono` from your controller method.
- there is no student with that id, so the first repository will return `Mono.empty()`. In this case, your `flatMap` operator won't be called and an empty publisher is effectively returned; no `StudentSubject` is created. Depending on the expected behavior of your app, you could look into `defaultIfEmpty` or `switchIfEmpty` operators to deal with that case
- there is an error. You can let the error flow throw the pipeline and being handled by WebFlux, or you can deal with it directly with `onError*` operators.

If you're new to Reactor, you can always add a `log()` operator wherever you want in the chain (as a regular operator) and you'll see in the logs what happens precisely.